# Does FileReader accept a relative path in an Eclipse plug-in project?

Tags: java, filereader

The following problems are happening under an Eclipse plug-in project.

It is all ok that I use the `FileReader` to read a .txt file with an **absolute** path (such as. `new FileReader("C:\\email.txt")`).But if I try to use a **relative** path (such as `new FileReader("email.txt")`), it turns bad and throws an FNE.

And what's stranger is that, when I try to print the current path with the code `new File(".").getAbsolutePath()`, it turned out to be **D:\Software\eclipse-rcp-juno-SR1-win32** (where I installed my Eclipse)...

I think the lazy-load design pattern of the RCP/Plug-in causes all the problem.Is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the lazy loading policy or anything else OSGi-related. An application is started from some **current working directory**. In your case it happens that this directory is as you posted. You can set the current working directory to your liking under Eclipse's Run Configuration (the Arguments tab).